# SQL: Adding new column to show count of ID by date

Tags: sql

I am hoping someone can help me with my query.

I have a table  with the columns, 'Date', 'ID_Num and 'Name'.  What I want to do is add a column at the end to show the total amount of times each ID_Num is within the data but based on the date.  So although 'ID_Num' 1001 shows 4 times in total, it is twice on the 20/04/2018 and once on both the 21/04/2018 and 22/04/2018.

EDIT:  I should have stipulated that I will be pulling several other columns with information, which I cant use a group by on everything.

```
Date       ID_Num   Name         Count
20/04/2018  1001    John           2
20/04/2018  1001    John           2
20/04/2018  1002    Paul           2
20/04/2018  1002    Paul           2
20/04/2018  1003    David          2
20/04/2018  1003    David          2
20/04/2018  1004    Stephen        1
21/04/2018  1001    John           1
21/04/2018  1002    Paul           3
21/04/2018  1002    Paul           3
21/04/2018  1002    Paul           3
21/04/2018  1004    Stephen        1
22/04/2018  1001    John           1
22/04/2018  1002    Paul           1
22/04/2018  1003    David          1
22/04/2018  1004    Stephen        1
```

Thanks

Comment: what RDBMS you are using? and what is the expected output?

Comment: Do a simple select all and have a sub query that groups the Id and returns a count.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something here, a simple group by and count should do it:

```
SELECT Date, ID_Num, Name, Count(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Date, ID_Num, Name
```

(That is, assuming there can only be one `Name` for each `ID_Num`)

### Update

Assuming your rdbms supports it, you can use `count` with an `over` clause:

```
SELECT Date, ID_Num, Name, Count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Date, Id_Num) 
FROM TableName
```

If not, you can use a sub query:

```
SELECT Date, 
       ID_Num, 
       Name, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM TableName As t1
        WHERE t1.Date = t0.Date
        AND t1.ID_NUM = t0.ID_NUM)
FROM TableName As t0
```

Comment: I should have stipulated that I will be pulling several other columns with information, which I cant use a group by on everything.

Comment: Perfect.  The count with an over clause worked a treat.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Date, 
    Id_num, 
    count(*) count
FROM 
    tabel_name
GROUP BY 
    Date, 
    Id_num
```

If you want name as well:

```
SELECT 
    Date, 
    Id_num,
    Name 
    count(*) count
FROM 
    tabel_name
GROUP BY 
    Date, 
    Id_num,
    Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal select query and then add a sub query to do a group and show the total.  Simple example below

```
SELECT Date, ID_Num, Name, 
(SELECT Count(ID_Num) FROM TableName AS CHILD WHERE CHILD.Id_Num = Parent.Id_Num) AS Total 
FROM TableName AS Parent
```

Comment: A short explanation alongside code is always appreciated.